# Round-off error when computing value inside range

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, rounding

For finite values `v0`, `v1` and value `r` in `[0, 1]` range, will the value `v`, computed as below, always belong to `[v0, v1]` range, or can it be (slightly) outside due to round off errors?

```
double v0;  // Finite
double v1;  // Finite
double r;   // In [0, 1]

double v = v0 * r + v1 * (1.0 - r);

if (v0 <= v1)
    assert(v0 <= v && v <= v1);
else
    assert(v1 <= v && v <= v0);
```

Comment: The assertion fails when `v0`, `v1`, and `r` are all set to `1./3.` (using IEEE-754 binary64).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I would be interested in `v0 != v1` and FTZ (flush denorms to 0) mode...

Comment: A remark: if any doubt remains, you can insure `v` being in the interval by using  [std::clamp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp)

Comment: A case without `v0` equal to `v1` and away from subnormals is `v0 = 7./13`, `v1 = 6./11`, and `r = 0x1.5p-50`.

Comment: @user2052436 The assertions fail even when `v0 != v1` and all the numbers involved are normal.

Comment: @alias: You mean like when `v0 = 7./13`, `v1 = 6./11`, and `r = 0x1.5p-50`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't see the example you posted till now; but yes. The original counter-example in my answer satisfies these conditions as well, though with more extreme values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be. Here's an example:

```
#include <assert.h>

int main() {

    double v0 = 2.670088631008241e-307;
    double v1 = 2.6700889402193536e-307;
    double  r = 0.9999999999232185;

    double v = v0 * r + v1 * (1.0 - r);

    if (v0 <= v1)
        assert(v0 <= v && v <= v1);
    else
        assert(v1 <= v && v <= v0);

    return 0;
}
```

This produces:

```
Assertion failed: (v0 <= v && v <= v1), function main, file b.cpp, line 12.
```

The value of `v` computed in this case is:

```
2.67009e-307
```

Comment: And same issue for `double v = v1 - (v1 - v0) * r;`. I wonder if there is an expression (without conditionals) that would always map into `[v0, v1]` ?

Comment: @user2052436 Well, `v0` or `v1` will fit (assuming both are representable as `double`s)

Comment: @user2052436 Try `fma(v0, r, fma (v1, -r, v1))`. Make sure you use a correctly working implementation of `fma()`, preferably one that maps to a hardware instruction (available, or example, on modern x86-64. ARm64, PowerPC, and GPUs).